# Install msodbcsql17_17.4.2.1-1.deb driver for django SQL Server connection?

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, django-pyodbc-azure

I am trying to connect django with SQL Server database using **pip3 install django-pyodbc-azure**. But when I install driver **msodbcsql17_17.4.2.1-1.deb** it produce following error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package msodbcsql17.
(Reading database ... 340765 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack msodbcsql17_17.4.2.1-1.deb ...
Unpacking msodbcsql17 (17.4.2.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of msodbcsql17:
 msodbcsql17 depends on unixodbc (>= 2.3.1); however:
  Package unixodbc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
```

Any possiblity to connect django with SQL Server?

Comment: Have you tried installing `unixodbc`?

Comment: yes i tried but it produce error unmet dependencies.

Comment: What OS are you using? if you're getting other unmet dependancies, you should be telling us about those.

Comment: i am using linux mint os 19.1

Comment: And what about the unmet dependencies... I asked 2 questions in my last comment.